# GitLab pages for group get a weird URL

Tags: gitlab

I have an instance of GitLab running on-premise (`gitlab-ee/jammy,now 16.4.1-ee.0 amd64`), and I've configured GitLab pages. Base domains are:

- https://gitlab.mydomain.com for the GitLab instance;
- https://pages.mydomain.wiki for GitLab pages.

In GitLab I've created a group called `group1`, and two projects within the group: `project1` and `project2`. The repos of these projects are:

- https://gitlab.mydomain.com/group1/project1
- https://gitlab.mydomain.com/group1/project2

Then I've enabled GitLab pages for all the projects, and I've got the GitLab pages published at:

- https://group1.pages.mydomain.wiki/project1
- https://group1.pages.mydomain.wiki/project2

So far so good. GitLab pages for these two projects are working perfectly, meaning that my configuration is mostly correct.

But then I wanted to create GitLab pages for the group itself. For this reason I've created another project in `group1`, with name `group1.pages.mydomain.wiki`. (As far as I know, this is the way to create GitLab pages for a group.) The repo of the new project is:

- https://gitlab.mydomain.com/group1/group1.pages.mydomain.wiki

Then I've activated GitLab pages for the newly created project, and I've expected them to be published at:

- https://group1.pages.mydomain.wiki

But when I tried to open this address in a browser, a weird thing happened: the browser redirected to the following weird address:

- https://group1-pages-mydomain-wiki-group1-79e94718ab74df906efcc5398d.pages.mydomain.wiki

And the group pages are displayed correctly. But the redirection is very annoying and ugly problem.

Does anyone have a clue why this weird redirection happens?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my problem. In my case, it was caused by the fact that "unique domain" was activated on my group pages project (https://gitlab.mydomain.com/group1/group1.pages.mydomain.wiki), and it was set to the ugly URL I was redirected to (https://group1-pages-mydomain-wiki-group1-79e94718ab74df906efcc5398d.pages.mydomain.wiki). I still don't know why the "unique domain" option was set on my project, obviously by default, with such an ugly domain, but it was. As soon as I've disabled "unique domain" option, my group GitLab pages started working correctly on the correct URL (https://group1.pages.mydomain.wiki).

Note that very similar problem may happen when people actually want to use "unique domain", and it is caused by some bug in GitLab. The bug is fixed, and should be distributed with the next release (after `16.4.1`). More details about the bug available at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/426435.